# Custom RunLoop Mode

Tags: objective-c

What am I doing wrong here?  What am I missing?

```
- (void)scheduleTimer
{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.15
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(wtf:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];

    // This works fine
//  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer
//                               forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    // This doesn't work at all - how come?
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer
                                 forMode:@"MyCustomRunLoopMode"];   
}
- (void)wtf:(NSTimer *)aTimer
{
    NSLog(@"wtf");
}
```

The documentation for NSRunLoop seems to indicate one can create custom runloop modes. Am I missing something?

(This is on the main thread of a standard GUI application in Mac OS X)

---

Update: Notice that I mentioned this was on the main thread of a standard application.  Therefore, I'm not running the runloop myself. It's all being handled by NSApplication.

Answer (score 5):

Are you running the runloop for that mode? Just adding a timer won't do anything if the runloop never runs in that mode.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the currentRunLoop only runs in common modes?

You should also try:
- (BOOL)runMode:(NSString *)mode beforeDate:(NSDate *)limitDate

and check things out with:
- (NSString *)currentMode

--Tom